# Set a "root" for each item in a SQL Server JSON result item?

Tags: json, sql-server

I have data stored in a database like so:

```
name VARCHAR(20),
host VARCHAR(200),
username varchar(50),
password varchar(50)
```

I can run the following as a query

```
select name,
host,
username as 'credentials.username',
password as 'credentials.password'
from tablename
 FOR JSON PATH
```

which gives me a JSON like:

```
[
  {
    name:'MyItem',
    host:'www.google.com',
    credentials: {
       username: 'usernamevalue',
       password: 'passwordvalue'
    }
  }
]
```

What I would like to get:

```
[
   MyItem: {
    host:'www.google.com',
    credentials: {
       username: 'usernamevalue',
       password: 'passwordvalue'
    }
  }
]
```

If I use a `ROOT` after the `FOR JSON PATH`, it will set that outside the array as the root name.

Essentially, I want each item in the array returned to be named for a value.  In this case, the name field in the select statement.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server is declarative by design.  This means you would either have to use Dynamic SQL or some string manipulation

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([name] varchar(50),[host] varchar(50),[username] varchar(50),[password] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('MyItem','www.google.com','usernamevalue','passwordvalue')
,('NextItem','www.askjeeves.com','SomeOldGuy','MyPassword')

 ;with cte as (
 Select name,JS=JSON_QUERY( (Select host
                                   ,[credentials.username]=username 
                                   ,[credentials.password]=password 
                               FOR JSON PATH,Without_Array_Wrapper  
                          ) )
 From @YourTable
)
Select '['+string_agg('{"'+name+'":'+JS,'},')+'}]'
 From  cte
```

**Returns**

```
[{
    "MyItem": {
        "host": "www.google.com",
        "credentials": {
            "username": "usernamevalue",
            "password": "passwordvalue"
        }
    }
}, {
    "NextItem": {
        "host": "www.askjeeves.com",
        "credentials": {
            "username": "SomeOldGuy",
            "password": "MyPassword"
        }
    }
}]
```

**If NOT 2017+ ...**

```
;with cte as (
 Select name,JS=JSON_QUERY( (Select host
                                   ,[credentials.username]=username 
                                   ,[credentials.password]=password 
                               FOR JSON PATH,Without_Array_Wrapper  
                          ) )
 From @YourTable
)
Select '[' +stuff((select '},{"'+name+'":'+ +JS From cte For XML Path ('')),1,2,'') +'}]'
```